# Remove call log from Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift

I want to remove call log from Apple Watch programmatically through an Apple Watch app. Can not find any documentation, and looking for guidance.

Comment: you cannot access call App in watch but if you have your own app in watch then u can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's privacy and security measures restrict direct access to sensitive user data from third-party apps, including call logs. Therefore, you won't find a supported way to delete call logs programmatically.